# SE site request: application research

Tags: feature-request, business, research, web

I love the SO-family sites, and want to suggest a SE site for application research.  By that, I mean a site on which individuals, companies and other groups could post information about computer applications, including both desktop and web apps, for a variety of uses.

There's a lot of information on the Internet, but it's disorganized.  Users of this site could identify the problem they need solved and list the applications they've found that are designed for their problem.  For each application, they could list prices, features, pros and cons.  This would help people like us (i.e. developers) and other people, who are either looking to create a better product or are looking for the same kind of product.  Ideally, this site will become a key reference for others as a comprehensive catalog of product reviews.

Comment: I am very confused.  What did you want again?

Comment: I think the idea is some kind of IT product review SE site, but I'm not certain.

Comment: To preemptively answer the question about my edit: I don't think this post belongs here, but I didn't think it would be closed or otherwise acted upon until it was comprehensible, and stagnation isn't good for anyone.

Comment: @Prix, Area 51 is no longer restricted to people who have received an invitation.  You can post site suggestions there directly, no need to ask on Meta.

Comment: @Popular Demand i checked it before coming here but it didnt see fit to be posted in there that is why i posted here, thanks for translating my poor englis into a very good text. But that's not all, knowin the fields and products available we also gain another field within all the research which is "available fields for new products that are possibilities, yet to be made and new ideas" just like onde day google was created or this days stackoverflow etc.

Comment: In addition a non-related example(that you can perhaps translate to it) would be: you want to open a screamshop, so you need to search for best location, audience target, cost, promotion, ad, product viability, and so forth... This would allow like said everyone to post their research allowing others to have it in such way they can see viability, cost, best locations etc ...

Comment: @Prix I still don't understand your reason for not posting on Area 51.  If your idea isn't fit for A51, it's not fit for Meta either; if it is fit for A51, there's no need to come here.  And I do not know what a screamshop is.

Comment: pardon me, ice cream shop ... didnt even noticed that eheh... well then it should be closed if it is not a good idea and not fit for both ... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Read carefully the [FAQ for Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).
2. Review the [current proposals that have reached the commit phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress).  Look at the proposal description, and think about how that description defines the potential audience for the site.  Think about how potential users might be attracted to such a site.
3. Review all of the highly-voted proposed questions for each of these proposals, and think about how those questions define the site.

Once you have completed these steps, you should have a better idea about how you can best [present your proposal on the Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create).